# Is it possible to change data type from String to Date

Tags: php, xml-rpc, type-conversion, openx

I'm getting in trouble where I was coding for connection using OpenX API with XML-RPC2. I get the problem that the data type is required by the fire function is the dateTime.iso8601.

This is my code:

```
$sdatetime = new DateTime('2013-01-01 00:00:00');
$edatetime = new DateTime('2013-06-01 00:00:00');

$startDate = $sdatetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
$endDate = $edatetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);

try {
    $result = $aClient->agencyPublisherStatistics($sessionId, 1, $startDate, $endDate);
    print_r($result);
} catch (XML_RPC2_FaultException $e) {
    die('Exception #' . $e->getFaultCode() . ' : ' . $e->getFaultString());
}
```

This is result error, when I run script above:

> Exception #3 : Incorrect
>   parameters passed to method: Wanted dateTime.iso8601, got string at
>   param 3

If I run `print_r(gettype($startDate));` I get the type data is **string** not **date**.

My question, for variables `$startDate` and `$endDate` how to make their data type to be `dateTime.iso8601` or `date` rather than `string`.

Thanks.

Comment: I do not know this api very well, but how about just passing the $sdatetime object?

Comment: Hi @nvanesch I have finished with this link http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.webservices.xml-rpc2.client.php , thanks for help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your agencyPublisherStatistics requires specific XML_RPC2_Value date object. You cancreate this by using.

```
$startDate = XML_RPC2_Value::createFromNative($startDate, ‘datetime’);
```

same for the end date.. let me know if this works..

Comment: I have finished with this link http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.webservices.xml-rpc2.client.php , thanks for clue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$sdatetime = date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime('2013-01-01 00:00:00'));
$edatetime = date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime('2013-06-01 00:00:00'));
```

**OR**

Check below links,

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.webservices.xml-rpc2.client.php

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51950

may this help you.

Comment: Sorry not working, it will return type data as string, I have resolve with this link http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.webservices.xml-rpc2.client.php

Comment: Don't, because for reference other people, I will give one up for your answer. Thanks.

Comment: No problem man, maybe other people got problem in php server bugs, because your answer there is link reference to the bug.

Answer (score 0):

use `DateTime::setISODate`

```
$sdatetime = new DateTime('2013-01-01 00:00:00');
$edatetime = new DateTime('2013-06-01 00:00:00');

$startDate = $sdatetime->setISODate(2013);
$endDate = $edatetime->setISODate(2013);
```

Comment: I have finished with this link http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.webservices.xml-rpc2.client.php , thanks for help me.